# Where to place native DLL to use Pocket PC emulator?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-mobile, pinvoke, mobile-emulator

I'm developing a SmartDevice project in C# (Windows Mobile 6.1 - Visual Studio 2008 - Pocket PC) and I want to use PInvoke. I have a native DLL written in C++.

When I run the application on my device I place the native DLL in \Program Files\My Project directory (on my divice) and it works, but I need to use the emulator and I don't know where to place my navive DLL (on my computer) in this case.

I tried to the working directory with relative path, i tried to DllImport the absolute path:

```
[DllImport(@"C:\John\VMDLLDevice.dll", EntryPoint = "Write")]
public static extern bool Write(char[] FileName);
```

But when I pinvoke the native DLL i got an Exception because the emulator can't find the DLL.

Where have I to place my native DLL to use the emulator?

Comment: I know that in the Windows 7 Phone framework you cannot use managed code (yet). So it could be a related issue.

Comment: @M4rc - PocketPC != Windows 7 Phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have these two projects in the same Visual Studio solution:

1. `SmartDeviceProject1`: the Pocket PC device application in `C#`.
2. `NativeDLL`: the Win32 SmartDevice DLL in `C++`.

Now you can follow the following steps:

- Select the Pocket PC Emulator for both project, in the Visual Studio Device Option.
- Deploy the projects; now in `\\Program Files` of your Emulator you can see the two new directories: `SmartDeviceProject1` and `NativeDLL` (Start -> Programs -> File Explorer -> Program Files).

Your NativeDLL.dll is in the `NativeDLL` directory, so use the following DllImport:

```
[DllImport(@"..\NativeDLL\NativeDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "Write")]
public static extern bool Write(char[] FileName);
```

And now you can run your application using the emulator.

MSDN additional Information:
[Using the Emulator in Smart Device Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289160%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to add your DLL as a reference to your Project, then in the Properties for that file, select **Copy Local > True**.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If it's native (hence the need to P/Invoke) you can't add a reference to it.  You could add it is a Content item and set it's Build Action to 'Copy Always' or 'Copy When Changed' though.